# What does "FPW" mean on a DS160 form?

Tags: visas, usa

My wife took my child's passport and DS160 to the Kolkata VAC (Visa Application Center). The DS160 for my child has been stamped, but they have written "FPW" on it. What does this mean?

Comment: Foreign Policy and Western Republics?

Answer (score 1):

I think it means Finger Prints Waived. Though I am not sure why it's waived for kids..

Comment: Can you edit in a bit more, like how you know this and from which country or countries you know this.